# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Can someone with a higher score make the following suggestions:

[xaml-only](/questions/tagged/xaml-only) can be  replaced entirely by [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) and

[xaml-editor](/questions/tagged/xaml-editor) is the same as [xaml-designer](/questions/tagged/xaml-designer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've retagged the [xaml-only](/questions/tagged/xaml-only) questions with the [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) tag if it wasn't there already.

Also, I've retagged the [xaml-editor](/questions/tagged/xaml-editor) questions with [xaml-designer](/questions/tagged/xaml-designer), as you're working with a designer, the ability to edit XAML by hand is a subset of the designer in general (it should probably be called something else, maybe WPF designer).

I didn't create synonyms because you were dealing with two and five questions respectively.